# webbrowser.open() creates a new Document file Instead opening browser

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I am trying to open a link in web browser through python command webbrowser.open() but every time i execute this, plus cursor(for selection) appears and whatever area i select got saved in file named "webbrowser".

Content of my foo.py file--

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("http://www.google.com")
```

After selecting i got this error-

```
/foo.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `"http://www.google.com"'
```

`./foo.py: line 2:`webbrowser.open("http://www.google.com"`);'

Here is the screenshot:
[image: screenshot].

Comment: You've got strange characters going on in the code you are showing. I see backticks and single quotes. I have no idea how your real foo.py looks like, but there are some shenanigans going on in there.

Comment: I'm guessing your `foo.py` file doesn't have a "shebang" line, like `#!/usr/bin/python` at the top. You need to add one, or invoke the Python interpreter directly (`python foo.py`). I'm pretty sure your code is being interpreted by your shell, not by Python.

Comment: @Blckknght How stupid i can be....was missing this line  #!/usr/bin/python.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing this line " #!/usr/bin/python" at the top of my code.